# access control using jquery in gridview cell in the telerik datepicker selecteddate event

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview, telerik

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="DOB" >
  <ItemTemplate>
  <telerik:RadDatePicker RenderMode="Lightweight" ID="txtDob" runat="server" 
  DateInput-DateFormat="yyyy-MM-dd" 
  DateInput-DisplayDateFormat="dd MMM yyyy" 
  ClientEvents-OnDateSelected="OnDateSelected"></telerik:RadDatePicker>  
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField> 
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Age" >
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="lblAge" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>

<script type="text/javascript">
function OnDateSelected(sender, e) {
if (e.get_newDate() != null) {
    var dob = e.get_newDate(), 
        today = new Date(), 
        ageInMilliseconds = new Date(today - dob), 
        years = ageInMilliseconds / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 * 365.25), 
        age = parseInt(years);
    //how to access the lable control
    //$("span[id$='lblAge']").text(age);                
  }
}
```

> can not access the lblAge control in the OnDateSelected event of telerik:RadDatePicker. if somehow rowIndex is passed then can set by td 
>  
>   var td = $("table[id$='" + gridViewCtlId + "'] tr:eq(" + rowIndex + ") td:first");

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example code that could be a viable solution for your scenario:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function OnDateSelected(sender, e) {
        if (e.get_newDate() != null) {
            var dob = e.get_newDate(),
                today = new Date(),
                ageInMilliseconds = new Date(today - dob),
                years = ageInMilliseconds / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 * 365.25),
                age = parseInt(years);
            //how to access the lable control
            //$("span[id$='lblAge']").text(age);

            // get reference to the HTML element of RadDatePicker 
            var datePickerElement = sender.get_element(); 
            // get reference to the current Grid row using the jQuery closest() method and search for the tr element.
            var currentGridRow = $(datePickerElement).closest('tr');
            // search for the label which ID contains "lblAge"
            var lblAge = currentGridRow.find('span[id*="lblAge"]'); 

            // exit the logic if the label is not found
            if (!lblAge) return; 

            // set the Label's text
            lblAge.text(age); 
        }
    }
</script>
```

Here is a short video that shows how the solution for this scenario was achieved. Also, it could prove a good way for debugging an application on client-side using the Developer Tools of the browser: [OnDateSelected set Label's Text in the same row](https://screencast-o-matic.com/watch/cFljrHraO4)

Here are some references that you may review for more information on the methods used to achieve this scenario:

- [.closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)
- [.find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/)
- [Attribute Contains Selector [name*=”value”]](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/)

I would also advise checking out the [RadDatePicker client-side programming](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/datepicker/client-side-programming/raddatepicker-object.html) article describing the usage of the RadDatePicker control's APIs.